# Get configurable products associated with simple products

Tags: magento2

I have to show the configurable products associated with simple products.

I have to show these configurable products in grid in product edit page in admin section, same as related products sections comes.

I am able to add that grid to list the products but hoe to achieve the other data like name and sku as i am trying to collect data from `catalog_product_super_link` table.

Comment: try this ref: https://webkul.com/blog/get-configurable-associated-products-id-magento2/